# Upgraded from Windows 7 to 10; asked to reset password after booting or waking up computer

Tags: windows-10, password-management

I get a prompt at startup or wake that I must change my password. I have a local account and I am the only user. How do I stop this? I don't want to change my password every day. If it matters, I signed up for a Microsoft account, but don't use it.

Comment: What is the message you see, and where does it show up? Is it before login "Your password has expired and must be changed"?

Comment: I got no message that password expired before logon, only that I must change it after password was entered. The excellent step by step answer fixed the problem. After going to computer management - local user account, I found a box checked "User must change password at next logon". I changed it to "password never expires". Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I get a prompt at startup or wake that I must change my password. I have a local account and I am the only user. How do I stop this?**

I've resolved this problem in the past with Windows 10 giving this prompt by:

1. Pressing the [image: WinFlag] Windows Flag key one time, start
   typing "*comp*", and then when you see **`Computer Management`**
   click on that to launch the console app.

   [image]
2. From the **`Computer Management`** console app go to **`Local Users and Groups`**, double click on the **`user`** account that is listed to the right that is experiencing the message during its logon, and check the **`Password never expires`** option to enable it. Press **`Apply`**, **`OK`**, and now reboot the machine and login again to confirm the issue is resolved.

   **Note:** If the **`#4`** option of **`User must change password at next login`** is checked, then that too will need to be unchecked to stop the notification.

   [image]

---

### Bonus Material (Home Edition Special)

- > To run `"wmic UserAccount set PasswordExpires=False"` in an elevated command would probably work on Windows Home. – [Yisroel
  >   Tech](https://superuser.com/users/368970/yisroel-tech)

  - [wmic useraccounts
    <sub><sup>by SRINI</sup></sub>](https://www.windows-commandline.com/wmic-useraccounts/)

    - [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Comment: note, this only works for Pro/Education/Enterprise, Home doesn't support this user/groups MMC snapin

Comment: To run "wmic UserAccount set PasswordExpires=False" in an elevated command would probably work on Windows Home.